# Compare files then delete the one with the greater characters

Tags: java, file, compare, delete-file

I have java comparing two different files but I would like it to take the one with the most characters and delete the other one. I don’t think it should go by file size because just one extra character added could have same size file.. Correct? 
Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.util.*;  


public class FileComp  
{  

 public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException  
{  

  BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader (new  
InputStreamReader(System.in));  

String str = ("compt1.txt");  

String str1 = ("compt2.txt"); 

String s1="";  
String s2="",s3="",s4="";  
String y="",z="";  


BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (str));  
BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (str1));  

while((z=br1.readLine())!=null)  
s3+=z;  

while((y=br.readLine())!=null)  
 s1+=y;  

System.out.println ();  


int numTokens = 0;  
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (s1);  
String[] a = new String[10000];  
for(int l=0;l<10000;l++)  
  {a[l]="";}  
int i=0;  
while (st.hasMoreTokens())  
  {  
    s2 = st.nextToken();  
      a[i]=s2;  
i++;  
        numTokens++;  
  }  

 int numTokens1 = 0;  
 StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer (s3);  
 String[] b = new String[10000];  
 for(int k=0;k<10000;k++)  
  {b[k]="";}  
 int j=0;  
 while (st1.hasMoreTokens())  
   {  
    s4 = st1.nextToken();  
    b[j]=s4;  
    j++;  
    numTokens1++;  
   }  


int x=0;  
  for(int m=0;m<a.length;m++)  
  {  
if(a[m].equals(b[m])){}  
else  
{  
 x++;  
System.out.println(a[m] + " -- " +b[m]);  
System.out.println();}  
  }  
  //////////////////////////////Change this:
System.out.println("Number of differences " + x);  
if(x>0){System.out.println("Files are not equal");}  
else{System.out.println("Files are equal. No difference found");}  
////////////////////////////////////
}  
}
```

Comment: As @JonSkeet would point out, you can't necessarily determine the number of characters by counting the number of bytes unless you know the _encoding_ used in each of the files.  That being said, if you are certain that you only have basic ASCII characters, then your approach of counting number of bytes might be OK.

Comment: The size on the disk might be the same, but the actual file size shouldn't be.

Comment: Is your question to determine the char-size of the file or conditional delete? There must be one question per question. You should explain why you overcomplicate your question with extra noise/overhead? Also, code cleanup must be requested at codereview site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
File file = new File("File.txt");
long l = file.length();
```

You can use the length() method on File which returns the size in bytes

Each character takes some amount of memory. So, file size shouldn't be same.